# How do I connect to wifi on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop as dual boot with win10 and I cant download anything from the web. Nothing that requires wifi works at the moment. I see many videos that just show a wifi symbol at the top but I dont see one. I also looked through many settings and checked optional drivers but nothing works.

I found the wifi setting today and it says "no wifi adapter found" with a question mark on a wifi symbol.

output for `-lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3040]
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: plase [edit] your question to include what you actually did try. In the meantime is there anything in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/806845/linux-not-detecting-wi-fi-adapter/) which helps?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I edited it rn.